# How do you import a CSV file in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, csv, import, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to import a CSV file into Jupyter Notebook. I am following the instruction on this article [link](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-plot-a-graph-with-matplotlib-from-data-from-a-CSV-file-using-the-CSV-module-in-Python.php). However when I change the file used on the link to my file I get this error [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGCMr.png). How should I go about addressing this issue?

Comment: Your code is looking for the csv file in the same directory as the notebook file. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Carry your .csv file to the same directory with your notebook (If you use windows as OS, it probably will be in **C:\Users\your username** as default). Then you better call your data file by `pandas.read_csv()`

Comment: from 'pandas' library, it is commonly shortened and called 'pd'

Comment: I added the file to the same directory and I increased the index size, however now I get an error message stating "IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer" how should I go about fixing this.